# How can I make sure Eclipse automatically detects XML files?

Tags: xml, eclipse

What's going?

My Eclipse does not give me the XML view for XML files.
Plus in the package explorer XML files do not get highlighted as those.

When I open the XML file, Eclipse opens the normal text view.
Also if files are obviously written in XML, and they have an .xml ending.

What I want is, that Eclipse gives me the tab switcher on the bottom of the editor.
Usually used to switch between an XML file's Design/Source view, with XML specific highlighting.

How can I make sure that Eclipse automatically detects XML files in future?

I'm running Eclipse version 3.7.0 on Linux Mint.

Thanks for any attempts to help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eclipse comes in many flavours and may or may not include certain plugins in the base installation. Chances are, you don't have installed the [Eclipse XML Editors and tools](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/sse/).

To install the XML tooling, you can just open *Help -> Install Updates*, select the Juno update site http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno in the dropdown and type "XML" in the filter field below.

To my mind the even better alternative is to NOT use the Eclipse as packaged in Mint (because most Linux distributions contain horribly old versions of Eclipse), but to instead download it directly from http://eclipse.org/downloads/. You may want to choose "Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers" eventually, as that contains the XML tooling already.

Comment: Linux Mint should be using Indigo, which isn't that old

Comment: Thank you, Bananeweizen! I had the packaged eclipse installed. After reinstalling the non-repository version I could solve a few of my eclipse problems. For example update to Juno. I didn't know about the delay between repository and non-repository versions. Why are there stable software releases, that don't show up in the repository?